# Every browser I use deletes my saved passwords

Tags: google-chrome, opera

Every time I exit a browser it deletes my saved passwords. I used opera before and it did the same thing so I switched to chrome but the issue still persists. The issue began after I was fumbling with my AppData but I have no idea what I did wrong so I have zero ideas on how to fix this. Every solution I've searched just says "check security and privacy" and I checked multiple times and it states that it saves my passwords.

Comment: So what exactly did you do to your AppData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every time I exit a browser it deletes my saved passwords. .... The
> issue began after I was fumbling with my AppData

The AppData folder needs to be treated with skill, experience and care.  Deleting whatever out of it can do significant damage.

Let us assume Windows 10 but the same approach works for Windows 11.

**Try a Windows Repair Install.**

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair and proceed
> normally.
>
> There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Start with Keep Nothing and see if that works.

**Check the Windows User Profile.**

Then make a new Test User Profile, log into the new User Profile and test Password saving.

Profile Damage means creating a new profile and if you wish to use the same User Name (we often do), then back up, Keep Nothing, and start again.

If you need to experiment, use a Virtual Machine for that. I make a copy, experiment, and keep or throw away my experiments.

Comment: I apologize but I'm a little bit retarded and have trouble understanding your instructions

Comment: There are two bold header lines. Go to the second one, then in Accounts, make a new test user account. Log into the new Account and see if App Data is working. If so, you need to make a new User Account for yourself.   ..... Then go to the first header line, back up everything and use (3) Keep Nothing and reinstall Windows. That is faster than creating a new profile in place.

Comment: ok so I made a new account and logged into my email there and it saved so how do I delete all my stuff? I click the Microsoft link and it gives me 3 things to download so which one do I get?

Comment: I would do the following:  First, log in as yourself, save Documents, Email, Favorites and everything you know about. Use great care when backing up. Backup to a USB Drive.  Then go to the Windows 10 / 11 link in my post, probably Windows 10, go to the second link on the page that comes up. Run in place.  At some point it will ask what you want to keep. Default is everything. Your main user Account is damaged. Do NOT keep everything. Uncheck "Keep" so it keeps Nothing. Reinstall Windows. Set up with your normal account and restore your data. Remember I said back up with care.

Comment: So am I basically reinstalling windows 11?

Comment: Yes.   You cannot dabble with Apps Data and expect to come out whole. When a User Profile is damaged (profiles cannot be repaired, just replaced), the way out for 90% of people is to back up and start over. Large lessons learned along the way.

Comment: Quick question can I use this to downgrade from windows 11 to 10?

Comment: Also in 6 months experience with Windows 11, it is less forgiving than Windows 10 and prior to increase security, so I re-double my point that you should back up, reinstall Windows 11.  Then use a virtual machine for experimenting.

Comment: Quick question can I use this to downgrade from windows 11 to 10?   .... If more than 10 days has past, no. You have to reinstall Windows 10 fresh. Since you are faced with reinstalling, just choose the OS you want.

Comment: I think I have answered all your questions and perhaps you can now upvote it or mark it answered.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the permissions of the AppData folder:

- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Enter the following commands:

  ```
    cd "C:\Users\YOUR-NAME\AppData"
    icacls * /t /q /c /reset
  ```
- Wait for ICACLS to reset the permissions of all the folders, files and
  subfolders.

In the future, avoid playing with the permissions of major Windows
folders, for the proper functioning of Windows and your applications.

Comment: What should I see when I input the prompts? Cause all I got were "the system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: You have done a lot of damage. Try a new user profile and see if that works and then follow through my post about dealing with this.

Comment: Did you relocate Appdata?

Comment: Also, have you altered the path to actually contain your username, or did you just copy/paste the commands? You need to replace the YOUR-NAME part with your actual username. Also, type c: before to ensure you are in your C drive.

Comment: No I did not relocate Appdata and I did paste my name into YOUR-NAME and I typed c:

Comment: Try `cd %appdata%` instead, then `cd` back one level to strip off the `\roaming` part.

Comment: This means `cd %appdata%` followed by `cd ..`

Comment: "Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\ApplicationData\Overwolf\BrowserCache\IndexedDB\https_ab784947d0d6a605c8e53c25f54a80ab.safeframe.googlesyndication.com_0.indexeddb.leveldb\MANIFEST-000001: The system cannot find the path specified."
here is an example of what its saying I did try cd %appdata% and than remove the \roaming

Comment: Is that the value of `%appdata%`????

Comment: I don't know this is just the stuff it shoots out after I input  `icacls * /t /q /c /reset`

Comment: A file is missing although its name is listed in the folder's data. Something is wrong. Please run `chkdsk` to see if it find any errors.